# Static files in developer mode, is it normal?

Tags: magento2

**Note :** I am in developer mode.

Is it normal that my CSS files are loading as static files?

I know it can be a stupid question, but i need to understand.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `loading as static files`, that they are loaded from `pub/static/` folder? How would you like them to load differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. 
One of the differences between the production and the developer mode is that the production mode will throw an error if it won't find the static file in the pub directory, while the developer mode will create the static file and use it.